# Meteor Restivus API call returns "Unauthorized"

Tags: rest, meteor, meteor-restivus, restivus

I am trying to access Restivus API with Meteor user hashedToken

Here is my code:

```
Transfer= new Mongo.Collection("transfer");

  var Api = new Restivus({
   useDefaultAuth: true,
    auth: {
      token: 'auth.apiKey',
      user: function () {
        return {
          userId: this.request.headers['user-id'],
          token: this.request.headers['login-token']
        };
      }
    },
    prettyJson: true
  });
      Api.addRoute('transfer', {authRequired: true}, {
        post: function () {
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.urlParams.id});
        var userName = user.profile.name;
            return {
            userId: this.urlParams.id,
            userName:userName
            }
        }
      });
```

I am trying to call it with:

```
curl -H "user-id: LGmaefwFZShu33GPA" -H "login-token: fG4HfWmPSp4Yd2HqUhNJEmAKcz4348Ng4WyyDaTHmLs=" http://localhost:3000/api/transfer
```

I am getting this response

```
{
"status": "error"
"message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Comment: I had similar issue, this worked for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597145/meteor-restful-authentication-is-it-possible

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
var Api = new Restivus({
   useDefaultAuth: true,
   prettyJson: true
 });
```

You don't need to input `auth` options if you keep `useDefaultAuth` as `true`